# Function that always return a "0" something weird

Tags: c

```
int ValidFirstName(char *firstname) {
    while (*firstname != ' ') {
        if (((*firstname>='a')&&(*firstname<='z'))||((*firstname>='A')&&(*firstname<='Z'))){
            firstname++;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

It is always returning a `0`. The input is a pointer to a string like `"sam  johnson:"`.

Comment: No it doesn't. I checked it now. I am quite interested to look at how you pass that string?

Comment: Please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you step through the code line by line in a debugger the problem should probably become quite obvious.

Comment: I also suggest you learn about the [`isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) function.

Comment: Provide a [mcve], including showing how you call the function.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks right, Try this main function:

```
main()
{
    char* name = "sam johnson:";
    printf("%d", ValidFirstName(name));
}
```